# multiple instance of a gwt application runing on the same server on different tomcat can't work

Tags: tomcat, gwt, gxt

I have a GWT GXT application running on Tomcat. 
this application has multiple instances running on the same server and if a user running 2 of them in the same time in the same browser the one which is running on the background start refreshing immediately when he/she try to work with them(at the first RPC call)
if the applications running different browsers e.g. IE and Firefox there is no problem.
Or the two application are running on different server.

Do you think this a possible tomcat problem or a GWT problem.

Comment: You mean you are opening two tabs in the same browser ? If so the two tabs might share the same server session. I don't know GXT but check if it can handle a different session for each tab of a same browser. If not, it might try to synchronize the two opened applications or prevent this behavior and fire a refresh.

Comment: I agree with otonglet, start two browser windows independently so they do not share any cookies, a websocket connection, or local storage. Then open the url with your application.

Comment: I mean opennig the application with the same browser application not necesarely the same browser on different tabs but in in different browser windows. But most probably the issue is with the RCP calls(nost sure I had to test it) Becouse if i run the application in the same browser the rcp call don't know where to call back(whic instance of the application in the browser) But it's onley a guess..