# Different GWT applications runnnig on same server interfere each other from same browser

Tags: gwt, browser, rpc, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I have a GWT application on Jetty. After configuring different accessing ports etc, user can start this application many time (for example 2 times) on same server machine. We noticed when accessing those two different instances from same browser, they interfece each, e.g, one kicks other session out.

If accessing from different browser, e.g, ie and firefox or chrome, there is no problem.

Of course, there is no problem if two applications are running from different servers.

Does anyone see same behavior before? How to fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "kicks other session out"?

Comment: When user1 logged in to first instance, after user2 login to 2nd instance, the user1 session will be logged out to login page. I just found that my issue is almost same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566072/multiple-instance-of-a-gwt-application-runing-on-the-same-server-on-different-to

Comment: What authentication do you use? One session is not going to kill the other session, unless you do it on purpose somewhere in your code.

Comment: Debugged a little bit, connection to instance1 has a cookie with name JSESSIONID; 2nd connection to instance2 will have a cookie with same name, but with different value. From browser perspective, it will wipe out the previous cookie, and essentially logout the first one.  I don't know how to control cookie name. Is it possible?

Comment: If you change the name, all of your RPC calls will fail. This cookie is used by XsrfTokenServiceUtil for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If your server uses cookies to maintain sessions, and both browser instances share the same set of cookies, then when the second one logs in, it must kick the first one out - how can the same cookie have more then one value?

Options to try:

- don't use cookies to track sessions
- don't require the second tab/window to log in, but recognize that it is *already* logged in
- don't support the same user pretending to be two users at one time

Comment: If they access the same cookie, they should have both sessions working fine - i.e. the second option that you mention should work.

Comment: Right, but evidently that isn't working, else we wouldn't be reading this question ;).

Comment: Every different login has different session information. On browser perspective, it tracks login with cookie the session with name "JSESSIONID", the 2nd login wipes out the first cookie out. Both 2nd and 3rd don't work for us, whoever logs in, the browser always gets the same cookie name "JSESSIONID", and it always wipes out the previous from whereever and whoever. I don't know whether there is some workaround for it.

Comment: In GWT JSESSIONID is typically used for security, not for login. For login you can set a different cookie with whatever name you want.

Comment: Login is one part of 'security', trusting the browser with its own authentication/authorization details either implies that the client could change the cookie to become someone else, or that the client has to pass a second token to the server, when the server could keep this in the session object mapped to JSESSIONID. Tracking a second cookie still will have the original problem if the second page clobbers it again.

Answer (score 0):

JSESSIONID is used for protection from cross-site request forgery attacks. Check how you set this cookie. Typically, you would set it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var info = "<%=XsrfTokenUtil.getToken(request.getSession().getId()) %>";
</script>
```

If you do it this way, you should get the same token (value) for each browser window, as long as you have a single session. Try to find out why you set a new value every time.

Also, if you need an ability to have multiple windows, you can allow duplicate cookies in XsrfTokenUtil:

```
final Cookie sessionCookie = getCookie(cookies, "JSESSIONID", false);
```

Replace false with true to allow duplicate cookies.

Comment: For the <script type="text/javascript"> tag, our impl uses pure GWT, and doesn't create the html page directly.

For 'final Cookie sessionCookie = getCookie(cookies, "JSESSIONID", false)', you mentioned XsrfTokenUtil. Do you means that I have to crach the library? or there is somewhere I can set it?

Comment: Pure GWT still needs an HTML page, which can be simple HTML or generated by JSP. GWT attaches whatever it generates to this page.